# Assign Custom property name in Aspose ImportCustomObjects

Tags: c#, excel, aspose

I am using Aspose [ImportCustomObjects](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/cellsnet/Aspose.Cells.Cells.ImportCustomObjects+Method) method to export data to an excel file. I have following C# class:-

```
public class ChildAccountDetails
{
     public string Name{ get; set; }
     public string Phone{get; set; }
     ...Other properties
}
```

I am setting the `isPropertyNameShown` parameter to true because I want these property names to be imported as first row, but at the same time I don't want `Name` to be displayed instead I want `First Name` as header so I added the `DisplayName` attribute to property like this:-

```
[DisplayName("First Name")]
public string Name{ get; set; }
```

But still it is importing `Name` instead of `First Name`. Am I doing it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a different attribute will not change the row title in Excel. You can use a different approach.

1. Set isPropertyNameShown to false
2. Set the title manually

I took the original code from http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/cellsnet/Importing+Data+to+Worksheets and updated for your scenario.

```
String dst = dataDir + @"ImportedCustomObjects.xlsx";

// Instantiate a new Workbook
Workbook book = new Workbook();
// Clear all the worksheets
book.Worksheets.Clear();
// Add a new Sheet "Data";
Worksheet sheet = book.Worksheets.Add("Data");

// Define List of custom objects
List<ChildAccountDetails> list = new List<ChildAccountDetails>();
// Add data to the list of objects
list.Add(new ChildAccountDetails() { Name = "Saqib", Phone = "123-123-1234" });
list.Add(new ChildAccountDetails() { Name = "John", Phone = "111-000-1234" });

// Manually add the row titles
sheet.Cells["A1"].PutValue("First Name");
sheet.Cells["B1"].PutValue("Phone Number");

// We pick a few columns not all to import to the worksheet
sheet.Cells.ImportCustomObjects((System.Collections.ICollection)list,
new string[] { "Name", "Phone" }, // Field name must match the property name in class
false, // Don't show the field names
1, // Start at second row
0,
list.Count,
true,
"dd/mm/yyyy",
false);

// Save
book.Worksheets[0].AutoFitColumns();
book.Save(dst);
```

I work with Aspose as a Developer Evangelist.